# Jitter on rigidbody2d object when attempting to pass through a collider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following setup:

A ball object that has a CircleCollider 2d with a frictionless, full-bounce (1) material. The collider is not a trigger. It also has a rigidbody2d on it, with no gravity, some mass, Continuous collision detection and Interpolate set to Interpolate. It also has a script with this code:

```
Rigidbody2D rb;
private void Awake() {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}
Vector2 lastVelocity;
private void FixedUpdate() {
    lastVelocity = rb.velocity;
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other) {
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Block" && isPiercing) {
        rb.velocity = lastVelocity;
    }
}
```

A few Block objects that have a Box Collider 2d on them (also not set to be triggers), nothing else.

The idea is, if I have the `isPiercing` property set on the ball, it should pass through. Otherwise, it should use default behaviour and the ball should bounce off the blocks as normal (which it does fine).

What actually happens is, there's some 'jitter'; as soon as the ball hits the block, it looks like it back-tracks on its path slightly. It still passes through; just it looks like it hit a speed bump along the way.

Do I need to move the ball forwards along its path when it enters the collision to make up for the bounce it's about to do (or is in the process of doing)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe get a clip of what's going wrong, but from what I can see, when the ball hits a block with piercing, then you're setting its velocity to its FixedUpdate() velocity. I don't know why you're doing this, but FixedUpdate() is calculated *before* unity does its physics calculations. I'm not sure, but it seems as if this may move the ball back slightly, like you are saying.

My suggestion would be to not set its current velocity to its FixedUpdate velocity.

Hope this works!

Comment: I'm setting its velocity to make it 'pierce' the block; if I didn't do that, it simply bounces off the block as usual.

Comment: Would enabling kinematic on collision work? Then it would ignore the blocks force.